# GROUP by ITEM number and the sum of Quantity to Stock

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count

I am trying to get my head into space on how I can GROUP by the item number and add the qty to stock.

My current code is:

```
SELECT dbo.InventoryItems.ItemNo, dbo.InventoryItems.DescriptionMed AS Description
     , SUM(dbo.InventoryItems.QtyToStock) AS QtytoStock, dbo.Locations.LocationCode
  FROM dbo.InventoryItems INNER JOIN dbo.Locations
    ON dbo.InventoryItems.LocationID = dbo.Locations.LocationID
 GROUP BY dbo.InventoryItems.ItemNo, dbo.InventoryItems.QtyToStock
     , dbo.InventoryItems.DescriptionMed, dbo.Locations.LocationCode
HAVING (dbo.InventoryItems.ItemNo LIKE 'CL10%')
```

and I am getting the below result:

[image]

But my expected output is:

CL1000 will just be in two rows with their sum.
Please help!

```
ItemNo          Description               QTYtoStock      LocationCode
CL1000          Square Seat Legs             4               CREST
CL1000          Square Seat Legs             93              DZ
CL1002          Square Low Back Sofa         5               DZ
```

Comment: I noticed CL1000 has 2 different descriptions and you are grouping on that - I would expect that could be an issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You clearly just need the right `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT ii.ItemNo, ii.DescriptionMed AS Description, 
       SUM(ii.QtyToStock) AS QtytoStock, l.LocationCode
FROM dbo.InventoryItems ii INNER JOIN
     dbo.Locations l
     ON ii.LocationID = l.LocationID
WHERE ii.ItemNo LIKE 'CL10%'
GROUP BY ii.ItemNo, ii.DescriptionMed, l.LocationCode;
```

All the *unaggregated* columns (or expressions) should be in the `GROUP BY`.  `QtyToStock` is being aggregated, so it is not appropriate.

Further advice:

- Use table aliases.  These should be abbreviations for the tables, so they are easy to follow.
- Qualify column names with the shortened aliases.  Much, much easier to write and read.
- The `HAVING` clause is on a `GROUP BY` key.  This is better handled (usually) using `WHERE`.  The `WHERE` will reduce the number of rows that need to be aggregated, which is usually a performance win.

Comment: Hi Gordon, last question, what if an item has 2 different locations, but still I want to get the sum of its quantity whether it is on different locations?

Comment: @TrishFernandez . . . Remove `locationCode` from the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`.